# Argument validation of abstract class

Tags: c#, validation, arguments, abstract

I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class FileClient {
     public abstract File GetFile(string Path);
     public abstract Task<File> GetFileAsync(string Path);
     public abstract void MoveFile(string Source, string Destination);
}
```

I also have multiple derived classes that provide implementation of the methods.  Since these methods are declared public, each of these classes must perform argument validation of the parameters.  For example, the code for the validation of the method looks like this for the two GetFile methods:

```
if (!IsConnected) {
    throw new NotConnectedException();
}

if (Path == null) {
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Path));
}
```

What is the best way to perform the above argument validation for all derived classes?  I can personally think of the following ways, feel free to mention additional ways.

### 1. Perform validation in every derived class

I personally dislike this solution because of code duplication.

### 2. Implement validation methods

Implement validation methods in a utility class or in the abstract class itself, and call these validation methods in every derived class.  I dislike this because I would need one new method for each existing method I want to validate.  Besides, this doesn't solve the code duplication problem as I would still need to call these methods multiple times.

### 3. Template Method design pattern

Implement the [template method design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern by adding validation in the methods of abstract class, and define new abstract methods that the derived methods will override.

```
public File GetFile(string Path) {
    ...Validation
    return DoGetFile(Path);
}
protected abstract File DoGetFile(string Path);
```

This is the best method I've found, but I dislike the fact that I have duplicate method names (Except with *Do* suffix) and descriptions.

### 4. Make abstract methods virtual

Make methods virtual and implement the validation logic in abstract class.  Derived classes will need to call base method first and then execute their own logic.

```
public abstract class FileClient {
     public virtual File GetFile(string Path) {
          ...Validation
          return null;
     }
}

public class FtpClient : FileClient {
     public override File GetFile(string Path) {
          File file = base.GetFile(Path);
          if (file != null) {
              return file;
          }
          ...Logic
     }
}
```

This approach is very clean, but I dislike it for the following reasons:

1. Methods are declared virtual only for validation.  There is no logic as they always  return null.
2. Derived classes will not know what to do with result returned by base class.
3. Base class will need to return a non-null Task object for asynchronous methods which will need to be "awaited" by derived classes.  This may or may not matter from a performance point of view depending on requirements.

Comment: N°3 by a landslide IMHO being n°4 the worst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a fifth approach using [***code contracts***](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970).

With code contract, you can implement [design by contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) using interface contracts, where the whole contracts will be automatically injected to all implementations of the whole interface during compile-time (actually using a post-compilation process).

You just need to define an `IFileClient` interface and a contract class. This is possible the most elegant and powerful solution.

See the following code sample:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(IFileClientContract))]
public interface IFileClient
{
     File GetFile(string path);
     Task<File> GetFileAsync(string path);
     void MoveFile(string source, string destination);
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(IFileClient))]
public abstract class IFileClientContract : IFileClient
{
     public File GetFile(string Path)
     {
          Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path));

          throw new NotImplementedException();
     }

     public Task<File> GetFileAsync(string path)
     {
          Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path));

          throw new NotImplementedException();
     }


     public void MoveFile(string source, string destination)
     {
          Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source));
          Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(destination));

          throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
}

// Any implementation of IFileClient will need to fulfill 
// its contracts, including derived classes of FileClient!
public abstract class FileClient : IFileClient
{
     public abstract File GetFile(string Path);
     public abstract Task<File> GetFileAsync(string Path);
     public abstract void MoveFile(string Source, string Destination);
}
```